# List view button to pass selected record ids on to new record for custom object

Tags: javascript, custom-button, list-view

I am trying to create an easy way to mark attendance.  I have a custom object "students" as well as a custom object "attendance."  The attendance object is related to the student object by a lookup field (student ID).

I would like to use the list view of my student object to select each student present.  Then use a button to create an attendance object record for each student selected and have it related to each student by the lookup field.

I am able to get the button to create an attendance object record for each student selected, but it will not populate the Student Id look up field.

Comment: Please post code.

Answer (score 3):

**Not tested, but something like this should work**

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js")}     
    var url = parent.location.href;       
    var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Student__c)}; 
    var newRecords = [];  

    if (records[0] == null) { 
        alert("Please select at least one record to update.");     
    } else { 
        for (var a=0; a<records.length; a++) {              
            var newAttendance = new sforce.SObject("Attendance__c");
            newAttendance.Student__c = records[a]; 
            newRecords.push(newAttendance);  
        }    
        result = sforce.connection.insert(newRecords); 
        parent.location.href = url; //refresh the page 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

result = sforce.connection.insert(newRecords);

here it should be like this

result = sforce.connection.create(newRecords);